# Hot reloading in typescript code in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, reloading

```js
// Immediately invoked function Expression (IIFE_)

var message= "Hello World";


(function pro(msg: string): void{
    console.log(`The message is: ${msg}!`);
})(message);
```

Above is the code I wrote in VS code using typescript. I read about this concept of hot-reloading online wherein you can basically make changes to part of your code and see changes to it without having to reload it from the start point. I want to be able to do this with a very simple program made in TypeScript using VSCode.

What i want is that i make change in my code for e.g. I change the text inside console.log() function and the result is immediately reflected in the terminal without me having to re-transpile the TS code into JS

Can someone tell me what am I missing since I don't know how to proceed, what settings do I goto to start this hot reloading?

Comment: Where ever you are compiling your ts code, user `tsc -w` it sets the compiler in `watch mode` so everytime you save a file, the compiler restarts automatically

Comment: yea this is what I tried but the terminal says the following: [15:09:01] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[15:09:04] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
what do I do now? I make changes to consol.log() 's text but no change in output, infact there is no output in the first place when i do tsc -w HelloWorld.ts

Comment: Ok first thing, `tsc` only compiles the typescript code to javascript. You have to then execute that javascript on your own. if you do a `tsc HelloWorld.ts` it will generate an `HelloWorld.js` file and you need to execute it using `node HelloWorld.js` if you want to auto mate this let me know as its too long for this comment

Comment: yes I do wanna automate this, please do tell.

Comment: since there was already a ts-watch related ans, I added a ts-node-dev related ans, its easier for starters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `tsc --watch` just recompiles the files and don’t run them. So to run it another package is used `ts-watch` which start compiler in watch mode  observes the output and runs the command.

This [Link](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/typescript-project-setup-hot-reloading-libraries-and-build-targets-99863e746aca) will help hoepfully

You can start compiler using npm

```
{
  "scripts": {  
      "start": "tsc-watch --onsuccess \"node dist/index.js\""  
   },
}
```

Comment: alright I added this this to my package.json file, now what do I type in terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't used any sort of package management and looks like you are just starting out

You can install [`ts-node-dev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) package globally

`npm install -g ts-node-dev`

Then you will be able to run ts-node-dev from you command line

After installation

You can run this command in the folder where you are writing your code

`ts-node-dev --respawn .\HelloWorld.ts`

or simply `tsnd --respawn .\HelloWorld.ts`

Result:

[image: ts-node-dev watch result]

Comment: Sure, `ts-node-dev` is a [node package](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.asp) which you install on your system. It is a package that will enable you to run typescript code. It is based on [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) which is another node package that emulates the `node example.js` but instead for typescript, for your commandline. Read more about `ts-node-dev` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev)

Comment: and what does option --respawn do?

Comment: Its like watch mode, basically `tsnd` starts a child process which executes your code so `--respawn` tells tsnd to restart the process or create the process again after if finds code changes. The process here is ts-node executing your files